# WSO2 API Manager Throttling

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to setup Global level throttling in API manager. Can somebody help me with steps.

I did read about it and it is supported in WSO2 ESB. I am not sure, how it can be set in API manager directly without any external ESB component.

Answer (score 0):

Throttling is available in AM. If you want to add custom throttling layer, you need to [edit throttling policy](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Adding+New+Throttling+Tiers).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please help me with sample xml to add in tier.xml to configure Global throttling policy.

Comment: I believe currently global level throttling is not supported out of the box. What i pointed is creating a new throttling policy.So, user can select his custom policy when publishing the API.